# Show input tags using JavaScript in the <div> tag

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question regarding javascript and cascading dropdown.
So on the main page I have 3 dropdowns and I  to show the result from the dropdowns. each of the dropdown has their own processing page and then we got all the values from the dropdowns, the program will show 3 input tags with javascript for the value processing. 
The problem is I cant make the javascript to work when the div is displayed.

Should I put the script in the main page or inside the page that has content to be displayed in the main page's div section?

As for right now I am putting the script on the content page

so on the content page,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var 
            total = parseInt($('#quantityRequired').text()),
            inputs = $('input[type="number"]');

        inputs
            .attr('max', total)
            .change(function() {

        //Make sure that current value is in range
        if($(this).val() > parseInt($(this).attr('max'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
        } else if ($(this).val() < parseInt($(this).attr('min'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
        }

        //Get currently available total
        var current = available();

        //Now update max on each input
        $('input').each(function(indx) {
            $(this).attr('max',  parseInt($(this).val()) + total - current);
        }); 
    });

function available() {
    var sum = 0;
    inputs.each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;
}
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<?php 
$projectName    = strval($_GET['project']); 
$thicknessValue = intval($_GET['thicknessValue']);
$baseplateValue = strval($_GET['baseplateValue']);

$query = "SELECT QTY_REQUIRED, QTY_CUT FROM COMPONENT
                    WHERE THICKNESS = :thicknessVal 
                    AND PROJECT_NAME = :projectName
                    AND BASE_PLATE = :baseplateVal
                    AND REQUEST_STATUS = 'OPEN'";

$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":thicknessVal", $thicknessValue);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":baseplateVal", $baseplateValue);

oci_execute($result);
?>

<?php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){

    $qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CUT'];   
           echo '<span id="quantityRequired">'.$qtyAvailable.'</span>';

           echo '<input id="cncQty"    name="cncQty"    type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="CNC" required>';         
           echo '<input id="scatorQty" name="scatorQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="SCATOR" required>';       
           echo '<input id="manualQty" name="manualQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="MANUAL" required>';
           echo '<br/>';      
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the script is already working in jsfiddle to distribute the value into 3 input tags.
I am able to show the input tags but the java script just doesn't work.

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the PHP code in the  tag of the HTML page:

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) {
        $qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CUT'];   
        echo '<span id="quantityRequired">'.$qtyAvailable.'</span>';
        echo '<input class="form-control" id="cncQty"    name="cncQty"    type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="CNC">';         
        echo '<input class="form-control" id="scatorQty" name="scatorQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="SCATOR">';       
        echo '<input class="form-control" id="manualQty" name="manualQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="MANUAL">';
        echo '<br/>';      
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain which part of the code isn't working ?
Right now, you should be able to "see" the input fields because they are placed in the <body> tag.
If you're not able to see the input fields, then most probably the problem is related to the database: the "$result" variable is empty.
Please mention what's wrong.

Comment: the input tags are showing fine but they are not connected to the javascript

Comment: Try the following:
`var total = parseInt($('#quantityRequired').text()); 
 $('input[type="number"]').change(function(){
        $(this).attr('max', total);
        //Make sure that current value is in range
        if($(this).val() > parseInt($(this).attr('max'))){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
        } else if ($(this).val() < parseInt($(this).attr('min'))){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
        }
 });`